# How is WCF service a communication channel?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, user-interface, ipc

My project requires me to execute a windows service that performs some back-end operations while a WPF GUI displays information to the user and also allows the user to do some configurations. To be more precise my back-end service performs anti-malware operations indefinitely while the GUI needs to communicate with the service to fetch data and for enable/disable operations.

Now for this communication between the GUI and my service I researched on this forum and majority of people suggested using WCF service hosted in my original service. I have done just that, hosted a WCF service in my back-end service Onstart() function. My GUI is also able to reference the WCF service and the buttons can call the WCF hosted functions.

Now I don't understand how WCF will communicate with the service that is hosting it. This is because the purpose of using WCF was to build a communication channel between the GUI and my original windows service. I want to expose the windows service functions to the GUI and not those I have written in the WCF service. I have researched a lot and cannot find relevant articles. Someone please help me to call my windows service function when a button is pressed on the GUI. If there are articles already existing please refer me to them. I am short of time and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to call your windows service's methods from your WCF service. There's many methods on how to do this, all standard C#, there is no special secret. Can you explain in more detail where you are stuck?

Comment: I cannot simply reference my windows service in my WCF service and then call its methods. That will lead to a circular dependency, because the WCF service is referenced in my windows service, as it hosts it. So how do I make my windows service methods available in the wcf service. Right now the wcf service is isolated from my windows service. Can you provide me a method to do that?

Comment: I have no clue how your project is structured or what code you have, I need to take guesses. Maybe have a common interface dll for both? That would be the normal way to solve it. Or let one have callbacks? Or events?

Comment: I am actually a c++ developer and this is my first time with c# and .net so I apologize if my questions sound too obvious.

Comment: I have a set of malware rules stored somewhere in a database. When a user clicks the 'disable' button on the UI these rules need to be disabled. If I use your suggestion and move the disable function into a common dll then both the wcf service and the windows service can access it, however the information specific to how many rules are present at that instant in the database is only available to the windows service. So the functions can be shared but how do I share the windows service specific information. Also could you kindly elaborate a little more on callbacks and events?

Comment: Not the whole function. An interface. That's like the header file. Only information *how* the method will look like, not the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF service should call your windows service's methods and they are in different assemblies, the easiest way might be to extract the methods you want to call from the windows service in an interface. Put that interface into the WCF service's assembly and take one such object as constructor parameter for example. Then work against that. Reference the WCF service assembly in your windows service, and pass the service to the WCF service after you have made the windows service implement the required interface.